# how can i paint row with different color in QTreeWidget (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

i have in my application that when i click on row i have the default blue row marked 
but beside this blue color i what to paint the row in different color via function not   depending on user clicked signal , in sort i need a function that i will pass the row index   and it will paint the row in x color.

Answer (score 0):

create a delegate function with an item role. set the item role in each tree item. Access the item in the paint event of tree delegate and paint the row accordingly.

Comment: Note that delegates are for the Q*View classes, not generally for the Q*Widget classes (although you might be able to make them work).

Answer (score 0):

For QStandardItem you can set the back ground role to your desired color.

```
void customSelect(const QModelIndex &index)
{
  if( !index.isValid() )
     return;


  QStandardItemModel* myModel = dynamic_cast<QStandardItemModel*> ( index.model() );
  if( !myModel )
    return;

  int row = index.row();
  for( int col = 0 , colCount = myModel.columnCount(); col < colCount ; ++i)
  {
    QStandardItem *item = myModel.item( row, col );
    item->setData(Qt::blue, Qt::BackgroundColorRole);
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that if an item hover/selected color is defined, it overrides the background role completely. Also, the question is referencing `QTreeWidget` and not a `QTreeView` with  a model.